# Fetch top X users, plus a specific user (if they're not in the top X)

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a list of ranked users, and would like to select the top 50. I also want to make sure one particular user is in this result set, even if they aren't in the top 50. Is there a sensible way to do this in a single mysql query? Or should I just check the results for the particular user and fetch him separately, if necessary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you could do:

```
select * from users order by max(rank) desc limit 0, 49  
union  
select * from users where user = x
```

This way you get 49 top users plus your particular user.

Comment: Good question. You could add a 'where user != x' to the top select

Answer (score 1):

Regardless if a single, fancy SQL query could be made, the most maintainable code would probably be two queries:

```
select user from users where id = "fred"; 
select user from users where id != "fred" order by rank limit 49;
```

Of course "fred" (or whomever) would usually be replaced by a placeholder but the specifics depend on the environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @topUsers table(
    userId int primary key,
    username varchar(25)
)
insert into @topUsers
select top 50 
    userId, 
    userName
from Users
order by rank desc

insert into @topUsers
select
    userID,
    userName
from Users
where userID = 1234 --userID of special user

select * from @topUsers
```

Comment: Just remember 'top 50' works for SQL Server but not MySQL, use limit 0, 50 instead

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution depends on your requirements, and what your database supports.

If you don't mind the possibility of having duplicate results, then a simple union (as Mariano Conti demonstrated) is fine.

Otherwise, you could do something like

```
select distinct <columnlist>
from (select * from users order by max(rank) desc limit 0, 49 
      union 
      select * from users where user = x)
```

if you database supports it.